# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un split de caracteres en mayúscula?

Tags: javascript, split

Trabajo con **NodeJS**, y hasta ahora, me ha surgido un nuevo problema en la manipulación de strings. Tengo el siguiente string:

> "/Lotus/StoreItems/Types/Recipes/Helmets/NovaQuantumHelmetBlueprint"

Lo que quiero hacer es obtener el nombre del ítem, el cual sería:

> NovaQuantumHelmetBlueprint

Y después, separarlo en palabras separadas con un espacio, es decir:

> Nova Quantum Helmet Blueprint

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías resolverlo usando:

- [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split), para separar por `/` el `string` y obtener un `array`.
- [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/pop), para tomar el ultimo valor del `array`
- `.split()` y una `RegExp`, para obtener un `array` con las palabras.

Así por ejemplo:

```js
var path = '/Lotus/StoreItems/Types/Recipes/Helmets/NovaQuantumHelmetBlueprint';
var words = path.split('/').pop().split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
console.log(words);
```

Comment: wao tu respuesta es muy sencilla. +1

Comment: Increíblemente sencilla y rápida, wao...

Answer (score 4):

Para resolver tu problema:

```js
var string = "/Lotus/StoreItems/Types/Recipes/Helmets/NovaQuantumHelmetBlueprint"

var last = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, string.length);

var UpperCaseCharacters = last.match(/([A-Z]?[^A-Z]*)/g).slice(0,-1)

console.log(UpperCaseCharacters);

//Si deseas utilizar cada caracter 

console.log(UpperCaseCharacters[0]);
console.log(UpperCaseCharacters[1]);
console.log(UpperCaseCharacters[2]);
console.log(UpperCaseCharacters[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function separarCammel(cadena){

    var tam=cadena.split("/").length;

    var nombre=cadena.split("/")[tam-1];
    var res = nombre.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').replace(/^./, function(str) {
              return str.toUpperCase();
            })
    console.log(res);

}

separarCammel("/Lotus/StoreItems/Types/Recipes/Helmets/NovaQuantumHelmetBlueprint");
```